# Best(Standard) practice to send multiple parameters to REST GET resource

Tags: json, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

Best(Standard) practice to send multiple parameters to REST get resource - Spring

What's the best practice to send multiple parameters on a REST GET resource call. Normally we can call GET call with path param &/ query. what is the best practice on how to achieve this(second and third).

```
Ex: /user/{username}/locaction}  - Its a standard way
2. /user/{username}/{locaction}/{mobile_umber} - is it a standard way? 
3. /user/{username}/{locaction}/{mobile_umber}/{age} - is it a standard way?
```

Comment: why is the password in the url? Authentication should be separate

Comment: Because they are nouns and in [the concern](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) you can choose anyway you want. However, if you are involving password I guess you are doing sign_in (a verb), then I suggest you make up the resources as parameters to be flexible and clear.

Comment: @codebrane, Password I just added as an example. I just wanted to show up there are many parameters. I wil modify.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of URLs, params tend to be more like [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) where you're invoking a function, e.g.:

```
/user?username=123
```

which is more like a traditional RPC call:

```
Object user = GetUsername(123);
```

`REST` represents a state of a resource which can be made up of many "states". Core information such as personal info, where `123` is the username:

```
/user/123 -> {"name":"Joe Bloggs"}
```

some aspects of the state of the user could change over time:

```
/user/123/location -> {"username":"123",lat:123456,lon:54568}
```

aspects of the user that are unlikely to change rapidly could be included in the core info `/user/123` or if they're unlikely to be needed by a client, they can be requested separately:

```
/user/123/mobile -> {"username":"123",mobile:"345345"}
```

A User `has` a location and a User `has` a mobile and a User `has` an age. A location doesn't have a mobile or age so those aspects would never come under `/user/location`. They would come under the URL that represents the object that does `have` them:

```
/user/123/age -> {"username":"123", "age":100}
```

A location can `have` an accuracy which can either be requested separately:

```
/user/123/location/accuracy {"accuracy":"-1"}
```

or more likely included in the response to `/user/123/location`.

So the REST structure in this case mirrors the object hierarchy, the `has` parts.

The REST structure could also mirror the business structure:

```
/user/account
/user/contactinfo
/user/location
```

it just depends how you want to expose the data that represents a User and their states.